# Get an exact regex match of an email value from a list of email addresses

Tags: regex

I have a text field which stores a list of email addresses e.g: x@demo.com; a.x@demo.com. I have another text field which stores the exact value matched from the list of emails i.e. if `/x@demo.com/i` is in x@demo.com;a.x@demo.com then it should return x@demo.com.

The issue I am having is that if I have `/a.x@demo.com/i`, I will get x@demo.com instead of a.x@demo.com

I know of the regex expression `/^x@demo.com$/i`, but this means I can only have one email in my list of email addresses which won't help.

I have tried a couple of other regex expressions with no luck.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Can you please describe your problem without focusing on the UI of your application? E.g. I have these email address strings, I use this regex to get something, but I get that instead

Comment: Do you need regex for this? Why not just split the string and do a `contains` check?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this slightly changed regex:

```
 /(^|;)x@demo.com($|;)/i
```

It will match from either beginning of string or start after a semi colon and end either at end of string or at a semi colon.

`Edit`:

Small change, this uses look behind and look forward, then you will only get the match, you want:

```
(?<=^|;)x@demo.com(?=$|;)
```

`Edit2`:

To allow `Spaces` around the semi colon and at start and end, use this (@-quoted):

```
@"(?<=^\s*|;\s*)x@demo.com(?=\s*$|\s*;)"
```

or use double escaping:

```
"(?<=^\\s*|;\\s*)x@demo.com(?=\\s*$|\\s*;)"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this expression. Just one little thing. It works perfectly if there is no space between the different emails: a.x@demo.com;x@demo.com. However, if there is spacing after the semi colon i.e. a.x@demo.com; x@demo.com then it does not work. Any ideas on how to remove or consider the space after the semi colon?

Comment: Got it to work with the spacing after the semi colon. /(?<=^|; )staging.servess@essity.com(?=$|; )/i). Thanks a million!!!!!